# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when changing tabs iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

Got a issue when going back and fourth between two tabs a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error is shown. Both Views can be viewed. Lets say I have two views A and B. If I go to B, I am able to see the view without any problems, I then move to A and that is fine. However when going back to B the error occurs. I Believe this is some memory leak but cannot find it.

A - Controller

```
@implementation FriendsViewController
@synthesize tableViewIB;
@synthesize userArray;
@synthesize xmlData;
@synthesize navigationController;
@synthesize localUser;
@synthesize interestingTags;

-(void)startParsingOnlineUsers;
{
    NSXMLParser *idParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
    idParser.delegate = self;
    [idParser parse];
    [idParser release];
}

-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    currentElementName = nil;
    currentText = nil;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"friend"])
    {
        [currentUserDict release];
        currentUserDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[interestingTags count]];
    }
    else if([interestingTags containsObject:elementName])
    {
        currentElementName = elementName;
        currentText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [currentText appendString:string];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:currentElementName])
    {
        [currentUserDict setValue: currentText forKey: currentElementName];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"friend"])
    {
        [self.userArray addObject:currentUserDict];

    }

    NSLog(@"ending");
    [currentText release];
    currentText = nil;
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    [tableViewIB reloadData];
}



//**********************TABLE CODE***************************************

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.userArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *Cell = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cell];

    if(cell ==nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:Cell] autorelease];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSMutableString *textName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"User: %@", [rowData objectForKey:@"username"]];
    NSMutableString *gender = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"gender"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = textName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = gender;

    return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSMutableString *textNumber = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"number"]];

    NSString *phoneNumber = textNumber;                                       
    NSString *phoneNumberScheme = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", phoneNumber];
    //NSlog(phoneNumberScheme);                    
    phoneNumberScheme = [phoneNumberScheme stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumberScheme]];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.userArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    interestingTags = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects: INTERESTING_TAG_NAMES];

    [self.userArray removeAllObjects];

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data]; 

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        self.localUser = string;
        [string release];
    }

    NSString *localString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"userid=%@", self.localUser]; //build URL String

    [data appendData:[localString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //build URL String

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.url.com/friends.php"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; //request with the chosen url

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; //http method
    [request setHTTPBody:data]; //set data of request to built URL String

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err]; //start the request and store data in responseData
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);

    xmlData = responseData; //store responseData in global variable

    [self startParsingOnlineUsers];

    [tableViewIB reloadData];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.navigationController release];
    [self.tableViewIB release];
    [self.userArray release];
    [self.xmlData release];
    [self.localUser release]; 
    [self.interestingTags release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Friends";
    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:154.0 / 255 green:188.0 / 255 blue:52.0 / 255 alpha:1.0];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.userArray = nil;
    self.xmlData = nil;
    self.localUser = nil;
    self.navigationController = nil;
    self.tableViewIB = nil;
    self.interestingTags = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
}

@end
```

B - Controller

```
@implementation FriendRequestsViewController
@synthesize navigationController;
@synthesize tableViewIB;
@synthesize userArray;
@synthesize xmlData;
@synthesize remoteUser;
@synthesize localUser;


-(void)removeArrayObjects
{
    [self.userArray removeAllObjects];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.userArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *Cell = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cell];

    if(cell ==nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:Cell] autorelease];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSMutableString *textName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"User: %@", [rowData objectForKey:@"username"]];
    NSMutableString *gender = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"gender"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = textName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = gender;

    return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:row];

    NSMutableString *remoteUserId = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"id"]]; //get the user ID of friend request

    self.remoteUser = remoteUserId;

    NSMutableString *messageText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Do You Want To Accept %@'s Friend Request", [rowData objectForKey:@"username"]];

    UIActionSheet *reportUser = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:messageText delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [reportUser showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view];
    [reportUser release];


    /*NSMutableString *textNumber = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"number"]];
     NSString *phoneNumber = textNumber;                                       
     NSString *phoneNumberScheme = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", phoneNumber];
     //NSlog(phoneNumberScheme);                    
     phoneNumberScheme = [phoneNumberScheme stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumberScheme]];*/

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        NSLog(@"Accept Friend Request");
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(AcceptFriendRequest) withObject:nil];
    }

}

-(void)AcceptFriendRequest
{

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    self.userArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    interestingTags = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects: INTERESTING_TAG_NAMES];

    [xmlData release];
    xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; //alloc the holder for xml, may be large so we use nsmutabledata type

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data]; 

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        self.localUser = string;
        [string release];
    }

    NSString *useridString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"userid=%@", self.localUser]; //build URL String

    [data appendData:[useridString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //build URL String

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.url.com/friendrequests.php"];//url string to download

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; //request with the chosen url

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; //http method
    [request setHTTPBody:data]; //set data of request to built URL String

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err]; //start the request and store data in responseData
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);

    xmlData = responseData; //store responseData in global variable

    [self startParsingFriendRequests];





    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

//***********************START PARSING***********************************

-(void)startParsingFriendRequests
{
    [self.userArray removeAllObjects];
    //NSLog(@"parsing init");
    NSXMLParser *onlineUserParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData]; //uses the NSMutableData data type to parse
    onlineUserParser.delegate = self; //set the delegate to this viewControlelr
    [onlineUserParser parse];
    [onlineUserParser release];
}

//called when the document is parsed
-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    //NSLog(@"parsing started");
    currentElementName = nil;
    currentText = nil;
}

//this is called for each xml element
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    //NSLog(@"started element");
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"friend"]) //if elementName == status then start of new tweet so make new dictionary
    {
        [currentUserDict release];
        currentUserDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[interestingTags count]]; //make dictionary with two sections
    }
    else if([interestingTags containsObject:elementName]) //if current element is one stored in interesting tag, hold onto the elementName and make a new string to hold its value
    {
        currentElementName = elementName; //hold onto current element name
        currentText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    //NSLog(@"appending");
    [currentText appendString:string];
}

//after each element it goes back to the parent after calling this method
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:currentElementName])
    {
        [currentUserDict setValue: currentText forKey: currentElementName];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"friend"])
    {
        [self.userArray addObject:currentUserDict];

        //eventually placed in table just testing for now

    }

    [currentText release];
    currentText = nil;
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    [tableViewIB reloadData];
    //NSLog(@"DONE PARSING DOCUMENT");

}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [userArray release];
    [xmlData release];
    [remoteUser release];
    [localUser release];
    [navigationController release];
    [tableViewIB release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Friend Requests";
    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:154.0 / 255 green:188.0 / 255 blue:52.0 / 255 alpha:1.0];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.userArray = nil;
    self.xmlData = nil;
    self.remoteUser = nil;
    self.localUser = nil;
    self.navigationController = nil;
    self.tableViewIB = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
}
```

> 2011-08-26 13:07:12.972 FaceConnect[2375:207] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSConcreteData countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6001710'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00dd55a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00f29313 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00dd70bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00d46966 __*forwarding*** + 966
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d46522
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50    5   UIKit
>   0x000613fb -[UIView(Hierarchy)
>   _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] +
>   174   6   UIKit                               0x0005848a
>   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 370  7
>   UIKit                               0x00056aa3 -[UIView(Hierarchy)
>   addSubview:] + 57     8   UIKit                               0x000b5a24
>   -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 563     9   UIKit
>   0x000b4dcd -[UITransitionView transition:toView:] + 129   10  UIKit
>   0x000ea0a7 -[UITabBarController
>   transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:]
>   + 459     11  UIKit                               0x000e8aaa
>   -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] +
>   64    12  UIKit                               0x000ea8a2
>   -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 263   13  UIKit
>   0x000ea711 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 352    14  UIKit 
>   0x000274fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119    15 
>   UIKit                               0x00229ce6 -[UITabBar
>   _sendAction:withEvent:] + 422     16  UIKit
>   0x000274fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119    17 
>   UIKit                               0x000b7799 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     18  UIKit
>   0x000b9c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +
>   527   19  UIKit                               0x000b7750 -[UIControl
>   sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 49    20  UIKit
>   0x000274fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119    21 
>   UIKit                               0x000b7799 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     22  UIKit
>   0x000b9c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +
>   527   23  UIKit                               0x000b87d8 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458    24  UIKit
>   0x0004bded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567    25  UIKit
>   0x0002cc37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447  26  UIKit
>   0x00031f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576   27  GraphicsServices
>   0x0100e992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550     28  CoreFoundation
>   0x00db6944 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 52  29  CoreFoundation                      0x00d16cf7
>   __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215    30  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d13f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979   31  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d13840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208     32  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d13761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    33  GraphicsServices
>   0x0100d1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217  34  GraphicsServices
>   0x0100d289 GSEventRun + 115   35  UIKit
>   0x00035c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160   36  FaceConnect
>   0x00002509 main + 121     37  FaceConnect
>   0x00002485 start + 53 ) terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException' Current language:  auto; currently objective-c (gdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not at my Mac right now, so I can't verify my assumption/idea.

I think it is related to the following line

```
xmlData = responseData; //store responseData in global variable
```

Here you make xmlData point to responseData instead of copying the object content into xmlData.

If responseData gets autoreleased, xmlData will point to something non-existing. Hence the next time the view appears the following line will cause a crash

```
[xmlData release];
```

If my assumption is correct, you should use the following code instead

```
xmlData = [responseData mutableCopy]; //store responseData in global variable
```

Answer (score 1):

In your -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated call, you are calling a Synchronous URL Request, this is usually a bad practice as viewWillAppear is part of the UI management system. A synchronous request is a blocking call and will "freeze" up the UI and could possible be leading to something being delayed.

I didt see the EXC_BAD_ACCESS in your debugging log, but thats usually related to an object being accessed after it has been released.

One more area to look at would be your NSXMLParser, it looks like you are releasing it prematurely.  In this scenario the parser is running and then it is released so there is no guarantee that the delegate may exist.

```
-(void)startParsingOnlineUsers;
{
    NSXMLParser *idParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
    idParser.delegate = self;
    [idParser parse];
    [idParser release];
}
```

If you look at the class defintion for NSXML Parser it says the the delegate is not retained.

```
// delegate management. The delegate is not retained.
- (id <NSXMLParserDelegate>)delegate;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Agreed with that non-retain suggestion. Had the same bug a few days ago :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you have released some object that cannot release.
Second view.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

then check.

Comment: now comes up with SIGABRT and a error log updated my question with it.

Comment: I have seen your code but i doesn't found method countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count: find this method in your project. this is some problem.

Comment: that method doesnt exist in my code. Ive never seen it in my life.

Comment: you have release some object anywhere in your code. please find that and comment that code.